# Ubuntu 12.04 on a netbook

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-netbook

I´m using Ubuntu 12.04 with unity 2D on a Samsung nc110p netbook, but is terribly slow . I have 2Gb of RAM and an multicore Intel Atom 1.60Ghz processor with hyperthring. Please help

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Samsung N150, which has a single core Atom, but it's quite fast, so the problem won't be the hardware. May I ask why do you use Unity 2D? 3D should be fine. Actually, I myself use Unity 3D with some minor tweaks in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Comment: Because unity 2D is faster :)

Comment: You just said it's terribly slow even so.

Comment: Yes but unity 3d is worst because of the efects. Thanks for answering